# Javascript global variable value not updated

Tags: javascript

I have two html pages that two javascript functions.

**page1.html**

```
<a href="page2.html" onclick="ex1()">link1</a>
```

**page2.html**

```
<a href="#" onclick="ex2()">link2</a>
```

**jscript1.js**

```
var abc;
function ex1() {
    abc='some text';
    console.log(abc);

}
function ex2() {
    console.log(abc);
}
```

In the console, I'm getting `undefined` when inside the `ex2()` function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to another page, where your abc variable isn't defined.

You need to render your variable persistent from one page to the other.

One solution is to use the localStorage :

```
function ex1() {
    localStorage['abc']='some text';
    console.log(localStorage['abc']);

}
function ex2() {
    console.log(localStorage['abc']);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I typed that var. Even without the var it is not working.

Comment: There was more than one error. See edit for the most important one.

Comment: Thank you so much, was stuck on this for a while, localStorage solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to pass value from page to page (page1.html -> page2.html)? If so it's not going to work as scripts are 'reset' with every page load...

You might use cookie(s) or localStorage to pass the variable - cookies are more crossbrowser friendly (local storage will not work in older browsers, Firefox will ask users for permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You are changing pages, which means you are loading a new execution environment.

the old variables are lost. You need to transfer them to the new page in the URL, or via cookie or storage.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not included an in a common html or jsp or php , soon on. then the variable `abc` is initiated again. The scope of the variable is limited within the page and cannot be redirected to an other page.